# How can I return an object containing tallies of each letter recursively?

Tags: javascript, recursion

For example: Given a string, return an object containing tallies of each letter.
 letterTally('potato'); // {'p':1, 'o':2, 't':2, 'a':1}

Here is what I have so far, but it's not working:

```js
var letterTally = function(str, obj) {
  var length = str.length;
  var current = str.charAt(0);
  if (length === 0) {
    return obj;
  } else if (obj[current]) {
    obj[current] ++;
  } else {
    obj[current] = 1;
  }

  return letterTally(str.slice(1), obj);

};
```

Comment: does it have to be recursive?

Comment: ... and does that work? not work? what does it do that you don't want it to do or not do that you do want it to?

Comment: The code does not work and I'm not getting a correct output. Yes it has to be recursive.

Comment: the code works as far as I can see. Make sure you're calling it with an empty object: `letterTally('potato', {})`

Answer (score 0):

Your function works fine as-is.  You're simply not calling it correctly – it needs to be passed an empty object as the second parameter:

```
letterTally('potato', {})
```

**Snippet**

```js
var letterTally = function(str, obj) {
  var length = str.length;
  var current = str.charAt(0);

  if (length === 0) {
    return obj;
  } else if (obj[current]) {
    obj[current] ++;
  } else {
    obj[current] = 1;
  }

  return letterTally(str.slice(1), obj);

};

document.write(JSON.stringify(letterTally('potato', {}), null, 2)); // {'p':1, 'o':2, 't':2, 'a':1}
```

Comment: I'm running these tests on mocha and sinon and this is the error message I'm getting: "Cannot read property 'o' of undefined"

Comment: I'm not familiar with mocha or sinon, but that error could occur if `, obj` were removed from your return statement.

Answer (score 0):

No need for recursive job a single assignment line with  `Array.prototype.reduce()` is ideally sufficient.

```js
var word = "potato",
   coded = word.split("").reduce((p,c) => {!!p[c] ? p[c]++ : p[c] =1; return p} ,{});
   
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(coded) + "</pre>");
```